# Is there a way to show local notification banner when the app in foreground

Tags: objective-c, ios7

The notification banner shows up in the background mode, but not in foreground which is normal.

I'm showing a `UIAlertView` / `UIAlertController` (ios 7, ios 8) when I detect a local notification, but it would be nice to have the same notification banner that pops up on the background, when i'm using the app.

I know that some apps are using custom animation in order to do this, but I'm looking for an API that could help me generate a banner in foreground mode. Or a hint on how to make a custom animation that looks like ios default banner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some Open-source code,

try looking at the Notification views here
https://github.com/cjwirth/awesome-ios-ui#notifications-and-alerts ,  you can choose whatever you like and display the message view instead of alert.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** of-course!

You need to draw your own custom `UIView` for that. I do it in my project. Just to give you a glimpse of how `drawRect:` of my custom view looks like:

**There is other intialization and animation code which I am not showing trusting you can build them up!**

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)iRect {
    CGRect aMarkFrame = iRect;
    aMarkFrame.origin.x = iRect.origin.x + 6;
    aMarkFrame.origin.y = iRect.origin.y + 6;
    aMarkFrame.size.height = iRect.size.height;
    aMarkFrame.size.width = iRect.size.width - 12;

    CGContextRef aContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self drawRoundedRectWithContext:aContext withRect:aMarkFrame];
    [self drawViewGradientWithContext:aContext withRect:aMarkFrame];
}


- (void)drawRoundedRectWithContext:(CGContextRef)iContext withRect:(CGRect)iRect {
    // This method draws arcs and fills color
    CGContextSaveGState(iContext);

    CGFloat aRadius = kAlertViewCornerRadius;
    CGFloat aBuffer = floorf(CGRectGetMaxY(iRect) * kAlertViewBuffer);
    CGFloat aMaxX = floorf(CGRectGetMaxX(iRect) - aBuffer);
    CGFloat aMaxY = floorf(CGRectGetMaxY(iRect) - aBuffer);
    CGFloat aMinX = floorf(CGRectGetMinX(iRect) + aBuffer);
    CGFloat aMinY = floorf(CGRectGetMinY(iRect) + aBuffer);

    CGContextBeginPath(iContext);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(iContext, kAlertViewBorderWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(iContext, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMaxX - aRadius, aMinY + aRadius, aRadius, M_PI + M_PI/2, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMaxX - aRadius, aMaxY - aRadius, aRadius, 0, M_PI/2, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMinX + aRadius, aMaxY - aRadius, aRadius, M_PI/2, M_PI, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMinX + aRadius, aMinY + aRadius, aRadius, M_PI, M_PI + M_PI/2, 0);
    CGContextClosePath(iContext);
    CGContextStrokePath(iContext);
    CGContextRestoreGState(iContext);
}


- (void)drawViewGradientWithContext:(CGContextRef)iContext withRect:(CGRect)iRect {
    // Draws the View Frame with Quartz
    CGContextSaveGState(iContext);

    CGRect aMarkFrame = iRect;
    aMarkFrame.origin.x = iRect.origin.x + 1;
    aMarkFrame.origin.y = iRect.origin.y + 1;
    aMarkFrame.size.width = iRect.size.width - 2;
    aMarkFrame.size.height = iRect.size.height - 2;

    CGFloat aRadius = kAlertViewCornerRadius;
    CGFloat aBuffer = CGRectGetMaxY(aMarkFrame) * kAlertViewBuffer;
    CGFloat aMaxX = CGRectGetMaxX(aMarkFrame) - aBuffer;
    CGFloat aMaxY = CGRectGetMaxY(aMarkFrame) - aBuffer;
    CGFloat aMinX = CGRectGetMinX(aMarkFrame) + aBuffer;
    CGFloat aMinY = CGRectGetMinY(aMarkFrame) + aBuffer;

    CGContextBeginPath(iContext);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMaxX - aRadius, aMinY + aRadius, aRadius, M_PI + M_PI/2, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMaxX - aRadius, aMaxY - aRadius, aRadius, 0, M_PI/2, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMinX + aRadius, aMaxY - aRadius, aRadius, M_PI/2, M_PI, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMinX + aRadius, aMinY + aRadius, aRadius, M_PI, M_PI + M_PI/2, 0);
    CGContextClip(iContext);

    size_t aNumberOfLocations = 2;
    CGFloat aLocations[2] = {0.0, 0.5};
    CGFloat aComponents[8] = {0.510, 0.514, 0.514, 0.8, 0.102, 0.102, 0.110, 0.8};

    CGColorSpaceRef aColorSpace;
    CGGradientRef aGradient;
    aColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    aGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (aColorSpace, aComponents, aLocations, aNumberOfLocations);

    CGPoint aStartPoint;
    CGPoint anEndPoint;
    aStartPoint.x = 0;
    aStartPoint.y = 0;
    anEndPoint.x = 0;
    anEndPoint.y = aMaxY;

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient (iContext, aGradient, aStartPoint, anEndPoint, 0);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(aColorSpace);
    CGGradientRelease(aGradient);
    CGContextRestoreGState(iContext);   
}
```

Comment: thanks i'll try to use this if the API provided by @ogres won't do the trick.

Comment: Sure, this answer deserves an up-vote for sure though :)!